# Delete table names with special character

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to delete tables that have special characters ~ and /
When I try to drop the tables

```
drop table ae1.AGR_TEXTS~
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '~'.

I am using SQL Server 2005 and SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2 collation.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Shashank

Answer (score 7):

Surround the table name with `[]` brackets:

```
drop table ae1.[AGR_TEXTS~]
```

Comment: Will that work? I'd suggest drop table ae1.[AGR_TEXTS~] - but didn't test your statement either.

Comment: @Arvo: You're right of course, the brackets should be around the table and/or the database name, but not both.  Answer edited.